# MySQL: No devuelve registros si uso "=" pero sí si uso like. Problema con los indices

Tags: mysql, laravel

Tengo una base de datos dentro de la cual hay una tabla intermedia llamada catalog_product que sirve para sobreescribir algunos campos de los productos, como precio y descripción basado en el catalogo al que pertenece. 
El problema se da cuando le agrego FK a product_uuid & a catalog_uuid. Al agregarle los FK y los indices entonces la siguiente query deja de funcionar. Funciona si solo tiene un indice, en el momento que le agrego el 2do indice, deja de funcionar. (No es necesario agregarle los FK para que deje de funcionar).

Entiendo que usar uuid para los FK y los PRIMARY tiene problemas de rendimiento y que seria mejor usarlos como BINARY pero para empezar a entender como funciona decidí usarlos como CHAR(36)

```sql
#CREACION DE TABLA INTERMEDIA
create table catalog_product
(
    catalog_uuid char(36)        not null,
    product_uuid char(36)        not null,
    description  longtext        null,
    price        decimal(16, 10) null,
    base         decimal(16, 10) null,
    base_fees    decimal(16, 10) null,
    taxable_base decimal(16, 10) null,
    taxable_fees decimal(16, 10) null,
    sales_status tinyint(1)      null
)
    collate = utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

create index catalog_product_catalog_uuid_index
    on catalog_product (catalog_uuid);

create index catalog_product_product_uuid_index
    on catalog_product (product_uuid);
```

```sql
select *
from `products`
where `sales_status` = true
  and exists(select *
             from `catalogs`
                      inner join `catalog_product` on `catalogs`.`uuid` = `catalog_product`.`catalog_uuid`
             where `products`.`uuid` = `catalog_product`.`product_uuid`
               and `uuid` = 'faec4395-a2b1-4b48-8abd-a926852c6cad'
               and `venue_uuid` = '8d426cb2-6d77-40da-8bb5-d279344535b4'
               and `catalogs`.`deleted_at` is null)
  and exists(select *
             from `categories`
             where `products`.`category_uuid` = `categories`.`uuid`
               and `uuid` = 'dc4692cf-aeb1-4771-802d-c4f7ecc6fcb8'
               and `categories`.`deleted_at` is null)
```

Si cambió la linea

```sql
and `uuid` = 'faec4395-a2b1-4b48-8abd-a926852c6cad'
```

por

```sql
and `uuid` like 'faec4395-a2b1-4b48-8abd-a926852c6cad'
```

funciona de manera adecuada.

**EDIT**
La query que obtiene los datos se generan desde laravel, usando

```php
$products = Product::sellable()
            ->whereHas('catalogs', function (Builder $query) use ($catalog, $venue) {
                $query->where('uuid', $catalog->uuid)
                    ->where('venue_uuid', $venue->uuid);
            })
            ->whereHas('category', function (Builder $query) use ($category) {
                $query->where('uuid', $category->uuid);
            })->get();
```

**EJEMPLO
La primera query usando (and `uuid` = 'faec4395-a2b1-4b48-8abd-a926852c6cad') no retorna datos.

Usando (and `uuid` like 'faec4395-a2b1-4b48-8abd-a926852c6cad'):

```
16daa5ae-4815-4521-b0f8-92a12471c1d5    181881971   Jamaica mule    Moscow mule con ron 28.00   0.0000000000    0.0000000000    0.0000000000    0.0000000000    1   1   1   0   719b61f7-0e77-4e7c-8e78-7a9b51791c29    dc4692cf-aeb1-4771-802d-c4f7ecc6fcb8    2019-06-27 22:21:42 2019-06-27 22:21:42
```

**edit 2**
Luego de agregar un primary key (autoincrement) a la tabla intermedia, ya no se puede reproducir el error.

**edit 3**
Luego de chequear el collation, gracias a Ado Peder, me di cuenta que este usaba el Latin1 por defecto. Intente con la query que esta en su respueta pero sigue sin devolver data. Ademàs intente cambiando el charset del servidor a utf8mb4 y el collate a utf8mb4_unicode_ci pero sigue sin funcionar

Comment: agregaste la respuesta en tu pregunta?

Comment: funciona quiere decir que trae datos?? igual las condiciones son raras, porque se contradicen entre ellas o se pisan unas a otras... Cual es el sentido de esta consulta? tal vez puedas mostrar datos de entrada y salida...

Comment: Ya pude resolver el problema agregándole un PK autoincrementado pero aun no encuentro la razón por la cual sucede eso. Y de verdad me gustaría saber para ver que estoy haciendo mal.

Answer (score 0):

Parece que tu problema se origina en el `collation`.

La consulta

```
SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE '%collation%';
```

te dirá los cuatro valores que afectan a la comparación de strings.

Dado que la tabla intermedia la creaste usando `UTF8MB4` (4 bytes por cada caracter), es probable que otro de los parámetros de tu servidor esté usando otro `collation`, como por ejemplo `UTF8`, que desde la versión 5.5.3 toma a `UTF8` como un alias de `UTF8MB3` (3 bytes por cada caracter)

Se puede ver más información sobre el tema en [el manual de MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-unicode-sets.html)

Te sugiero que pruebes forzando un `collation` durante tu comparación con '=', así:

```
and `uuid` = _utf8mb4'faec4395-a2b1-4b48-8abd-a926852c6cad' COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Esto forzaría a las 2 partes del '=' a trabajar con la misma `collation`, independientemente de los valores configurados para la conexión, la base y las tablas.

Más info:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-collate.html
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-literal.html

Comment: Luego de chequear el collation, me di cuenta que este usaba el Latin1 por defecto. Intente con la query que me brindaste pero sigue sin devolver data. Ademàs intente cambiandoel charset del servidor a utf8mb4 y el collate a utf8mb4_unicode_ci pero sigue sin funcionar

Comment: @NickAguilarH Probaste forzándolo como te sugerí en la respuesta? Si con mi sugerencia te funciona entonces hay más parámetros que pueden influir en la comparación ... pero si con mi sugerencia tampoco funciona entonces sería otra cosa y no el collation.

Comment: Si, probé forzándolo, actualice mi comentario y también el post principal.

Comment: @NickAguilarH para ir eliminando variables ... en lugar de usar toda la consulta de tu pregunta probemos sólo con `select *
from products where uuid = 'faec4395-a2b1-4b48-8abd-a926852c6cad'` y con `select *
from products where uuid like 'faec4395-a2b1-4b48-8abd-a926852c6cad'`
Sin el resto de las comparaciones, sigue pasando que uno devuelve 1 resultado y el otro 0?